# Docker nginx reverse proxy error - 502 bad gateway - connection refused

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm having a problem with getting to work my NGINX reverse proxy on Docker.
When I access:

1. local.lab - NGINX responds with expected index.html page
2. 127.0.0.1:2000 or 127.0.0.1:2001 or 127.0.0.1:2002 - service works and I get expected results
3. local.lab/a1 or local.lab/a2 or local.lab/a3 - I get "502 Bad Gateway" error.
   Detailed error from nginx log:
   `2021/02/25 18:20:48 [error] 30#30: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: local.lab, request: "GET /a2 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:2006/", host: "www.local.lab"`

I tried to add `network_mode: host` to nginx service in docker compose without success.

I'm using docker compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
nginx:
container_name: lab-nginx
image: nginx:latest
restart: always
depends_on:
  - http1
  - http2
  - http3
volumes:
  - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html/
  - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  - ./error_log/error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
  - ./cert:/var/log/nginx/cert/
ports:
  - 80:80
  - 443:443
http1:
container_name: lab-http1
image: httpd:latest
restart: always
#    build:
#      context: ./apache_service
ports:
  - 2000:80
  - 2005:443
volumes:
  - ./apache/index1.html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html
http2:
container_name: lab-http2
image: httpd:latest
restart: always
ports:
  - 2001:80
  - 2006:443
volumes:
  - ./apache/index2.html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html
http3:
container_name: lab-http3
image: httpd:latest
restart: always
ports:
  - 2002:80
  - 2007:443
volumes:
  - ./apache/index3.html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html
```

My nginx config:

```
 worker_processes auto;
 events { worker_connections  1024;}
   error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    http{
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        server_name local.lab;

        ssl_certificate /var/log/nginx/cert/local.lab.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/log/nginx/cert/local.lab.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;

            location / {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                index index.html;
            }

            location /a1 {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2000/;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            }
            location /a2 {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2001/;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            }
            location /a3 {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2002/;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            }
    }
 }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse proxy configuration in NGINX should reference the internal ports of your services, not the external ports they are mapped to in the docker-compose.yml. The services all have different names running in different containers so they can run on the same port (80 in this case) and use the service name, not the loopback address. You need to map them to different ports externally though because you can't have more than one service per port on your host.

For example:

```
location /a1 {
    proxy_pass http://http1:80/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}

location /a2 {
    proxy_pass http://http2:80/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}

location /a3 {
    proxy_pass http://http3:80/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}
```

Comment: If I would want to proxy_pass localhost:2019 (new service independent of the current docker-compose file) what would I have to change?

Comment: Might be good to post a new question... if it is actually running on localhost then you will need to set up host routing, otherwise just use the service_name:internal_port in the proxy_pass config.

Comment: Thanks for answering!